# Laravel css url does not work

Tags: css, laravel, url, fonts

Hello im trying to add a costum font from file to my website I have tried everything but I keep getting the 404 error, What am I doing wrong

this is my file structure with my css url code:
[File structure with css url code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjXGQ.png)

and this is the error i get:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HemeN.png)

hope you guys can help me out !

Comment: It is better to include code in your posts and not attach an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix the extension:

`starwars.tff` -> `starwars.ttf`

Answer (score 1):

Your error message shows that the path to the file is not correct, and the file name is not correct.

Try setting your path absolutely

```
src:url("/fonts/starwars.ttf")
```

Make sure your file name with extension is correct.

```
starswars.ttf
```